# Can't get appcelerator module/widget SocialShare to work

Tags: module, widget, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to incorporate a sharing module for android/ios in Appcelerator Titanium.
I have tried installing the widget through gittio
http://gitt.io/component/com.alcoapps.socialshare
And also tried installing the module from the Studio's help menu.

When running the app, the following error is thrown:

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error Couldn't find module: 
/com.alcoapps.socialshare/com.alcoapps.socialshare for architecture: x86_64
```

Would this simply mean the module is outdated for my system ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this module: https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework

it is newer and supports the current SDK

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it only supports ios though.

Comment: the widget you've mentioned uses TiSocial.Framework for iOS! https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/socialshare/tree/master/app/widgets/com.alcoapps.socialshare#dependencies you can still use that widget but use the newer version of the module i've linked. Also: the android part just uses a normal share intent, so no module involved: https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/socialshare/blob/master/app/widgets/com.alcoapps.socialshare/lib/com.alcoapps.socialshare.js#L20

Comment: I have the social framework in my modules, and the widget in my widgets folder, but it still throws the same error message

Comment: how your tiapp.xml looks like

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Apparently installing the widget through gittio did not download the 'lib' folder for some reason.
After adding it the widget worked.